# how to get contacts from contentprovider where contact_id max of specific number

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-query

I want to get all contacts that has an id larger than a specific number.

My code is:

```
    String xml = "[";
    max_contact_id="1000";

    final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    Cursor cur = content.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" > ?",
            new String[]{max_contact_id}, sortOrder);
```

But it won't work.

Comment: Try to decrease this number e.g. to 10, and put some projection instead null. It's hard to get number of 1000 contacts, may you just not achieve that number.

Answer (score 0):

> Implement your Fragment or Activity with
>   LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

```
implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 



 @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,
                // Select only email addresses
                null, null, null);
    }

@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();


        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.NUMBER);
            String name = cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.NAME);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }



    }
```